# Nested Generic Interfaces with Inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Definition:

```
public interface IRecord { }
public interface IEvent<out T> { }
public interface IHandler<out T> { }

public class RecordA : IRecord { }
public class EventA : IEvent<RecordA> { }
public class HandlerA : IHandler<IEvent<IRecord>> { }
```

Code:

```
IHandler<EventA> h1 = new HandlerA() as IHandler<EventA>;
IHandler<IEvent<RecordA>> h2 = new HandlerA() as IHandler<IEvent<RecordA>>;
```

Why both h1 and h2 result into NULL?

Based on definition of [HandlerA] it should be able to handle any IEvent[IRecord] type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) to the [contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/dd469484.aspx) in the `IHandler` interface and it will work:

```
public interface IHandler<in T> { }

//It works
var h1 = new HandlerA() as IHandler<EventA>;
var h2 = new HandlerA() as IHandler<IEvent<RecordA>>;
```

Comment: That is correct, maybe if you can also indicate why it works with contravariance (I'll do more reading on it too)